# Upgrading 18.04 and getting error "Possible missing firmware"

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am attempting to upgrade my 18.04 ubuntu installation.

I've done:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

When I do

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get

```
"Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"
```

I then looked more closely at the output of

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

And I saw:

```
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (470.182.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-150-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
```

I think an old custom nvidia driver is possibly the problem, but I'm stuck with what to do next.

Comment: My 1st action would be to remove it and then do the upgrade again. And if all else fails do an install instead of an upgrade. Just make a backup of your data and confirm you know how to restore it before you procede.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by:

```
Rebooting
Choosing recovery mode from grub
Choosing "root"
apt-get purge nvidia*
apt-get autoremove
```